# axis in numpy.ufunc.outer

Tags: python, numpy

`numpy.ufunc.outer` is like `Mathematica` `Outer[]`, but what I can't seem to figure out is how to treat a two dimensional array as a one dimensional array of one dimensional arrays. That is, suppose
`a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]` and `b = [[4, 5], [6, 7]]`. I want to compute the two dimensional array whose `ij`th element is the distance (however I define it) between the ith row of `a` and the jth row of `b`, so in this case, if we use the `supnorm` distance, the result will be `[[3, 5], [1, 3]]`. Obviously one can write a loop, but that seems morally wrong, and precisely what `ufunc.outer` is meant to avoid.

Comment: Often that moral wrong is clearer than a word description.  Which `ufunc` do you have in mind?  Often we use `broadcasting` instead of the `outer` method.

Comment: @hpaulj I am computing distances between time series, it's a little complicated...

Comment: Do you actually have a ufunc for the supnorm, or whatever vector-vector computation you want to perform? `numpy.ufunc.outer` is a method of NumPy ufunc objects, not something you can use with arbitrary callables. You can't just `def supnorm(x, y): ...` and chuck it into `numpy.ufunc.outer`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I did NOT know that. But I think the broadcast scheme might do the right thing (there is still the axis issue...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [309]: a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]); b = np.array([[4, 5], [6, 7]])
```

With `broadcasting` we can take the row differences:

```
In [310]: a[:,None,:]-b[None,:,:]                                                              
Out[310]: 
array([[[-3, -3],
        [-5, -5]],

       [[-1, -1],
        [-3, -3]]])
```

and reduce those with the max/abs on the  last axis (I think that's what you mean by the `sup norm`:

```
In [311]: np.abs(a[:,None,:]-b[None,:,:]).max(axis=-1)                                         
Out[311]: 
array([[3, 5],
       [1, 3]])
```

With `subtract.outer`, I have to select a subset of the results, and then transpose:

```
In [318]: np.subtract.outer(a,b)[:,[0,1],:,[0,1]].transpose(2,1,0)                             
Out[318]: 
array([[[-3, -3],
        [-1, -1]],

       [[-5, -5],
        [-3, -3]]])
```

I don't see any `axis` controls in the `outer` docs.  Since broadcasting gives finer control, I haven't seen much use of the `ufunc.outer` feature.

Comment: Thank you! I assume that if instead of max we have some user defined function, there is a way to .apply(foo, axis=-1)?

Comment: Also look at `scipy` `pdist`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful (I am experimenting with time warp distances, so none of these are directly applicable, but they will be down the road!